# Crockford explanation of private properties

Tags: javascript, private

I read this: [private Javascript variables](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html) from Crockford site

but I have some perplexity on his terminology:

here he says:

> The members of an object are all
>   public members Ex. `this.membername =
>   value;

after:

> Private variables are not accessible
>   to the outside, nor are they
>   accessible to the object's own public
>   methods.

and then:

> A privileged method is able to access
>   the private variables and methods, and
>   is itself accessible to the public
>   methods and the outside

So it seems as privileged methods are different from public methods but if I do:

```
function S()
{
   var a = 11; // PRIVATE
   this.get = function() { return a; }; // PUBLIC AND PRIVILEGED???
}

new S().get();
```

there `get` method is a public method and also a privileged method... so
when he says the public methods can't access private member what is he concerning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The only way that `get` is able to access `a` is through closure, so that effectively makes it a privileged method. Whether it is public or not has nothing to do with the fact that it *is* privileged.

Comment: But which are the public methods that cannot access to private? Really I don't see that, if we say that a privileged method is a way to say that a private variable is accessed through a public method!!

Answer (score 1):

To answer specifically your question about public methods, since you seem to understand the idea of privilaged, consider from your example:

```
S.prototype.something = function ...
```

This would be public but not privilaged since it can't access the private variable `a`

Answer (score 0):

That you can get the value of `a` which is a private member of `S` doesn't mean that you could "access" `a`. For example, you can't change the value of `a` unless a method, like `set`, is provided to do that. You are given a method (an interface, if you may) `get` which is "previleged" to get the value of `a` which is a private member of S.